# Is Kusto query ingestion (.set-or-append) guaranteed if run async

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I cannot find the answer from the document.

If I run query ingestion using

`.set-or-append async`

will the result be guaranteed?

Currently, we are running all those data grooming operations without the `async` keyword. Sometimes they jam our cluster, but we know they fail and can recover from a queue.

If we fire them async, then we don't have any control to know if they fail and recover.
What are the recommended ways to handle this?

For more context detail, we have to groom the data from 2 very large tables to the other 4 tables with aggregated data. UpdatePolicy is not really applied in this use case. We only need to run it once a week, since it's more like a weekly or monthly based aggregation. Unfortunately, when they run, we seem to easily get throttled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently we are running all those data grooming operations without the async keyword. Sometimes they jam our cluster, but we know they fail and can recover from a queue.

This isn't accurate - these commands don't [currently] get queued. if a command fails, due to whatever reason (transient failure, throttling due to hitting ingestion capacity, etc.) - it fails, and it's the responsibility of the caller to retry it (if it makes sense to do so, based on the kind of the failure)

> For more context detail, we have to groom the data from 2 very large tables to other 4 tables with aggregated data. UpdatePolicy is not really applied in this use case. We only need to run it once a week, since it's more like a weekly or monthly based aggregation. Unfortunately, when they run, we seem to easily get throttled.

The commands being frequently throttled is an indication that your cluster is frequently fully utilizing its [ingestion capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy#ingestion-capacity). as ingestion capacity scales linearly with the amount of cores in the cluster, you could choose to [scale out/up your cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/manage-cluster-choose-sku), to get additional ingestion capacity (you could also do that on a schedule, temporarily, only when your additional ingestion load is expected to run).

note that you can (and probably should) monitor the state/status of commands you run using the `async` keyword - that could be done using the `.show operations` command ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/operations))

Comment: sorry, when I said "jam", I meant our services (callers) are making too many calls concurrently, and then got throttled, so other areas will become timed out.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can check operation; however, it's a backend processor. It sends a few thousands `.set-or-append`, I am not going to have another service to check those operation and check the status using operation id... (hmm, maybe I should if I am going to use `async`?). But it sounds like the answer is simple, `async` query ingestion is not guaranteed, the caller has to be responsible for recovering. Is that right?